# Need help modifying d3.js Collapsible Force Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am modifying the d3.js Collapsible Force Layout where the nodes are given as circles.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288

I changed it to a group g and attached the circle into the g. The problem is that in the tick function when I change from

```
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

to

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
```

the nodes are all displaced.

I have changed the reference to node so node refers to the group g in the second case.

I have created force layouts and have done this a lot of times but never faced this problem.
Is it because of the d3.tree.layout? I don't know. Please help.

[image: Initial nodes]

[image: Displaced nodes]

I have tried a few more times with other svg elements like text and rect and I found out that the problem occurs only when there is circle involved and I need to give attributes like cx and cy to text and rect even though these elements don't have these attributes, to make them work.

So please help someone. Totally confused.

Code::

```
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
        node = svg.selectAll(".node");

    link = link.data(force.links());

    // Exit any old links.
    link.exit().remove();

    // Enter any new links.
    link.enter().insert("line",".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d,i) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    // Update the nodes…
    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id; }).style("fill", color);

    // Exit any old nodes.
    node.exit().remove();

    // Enter any new nodes.
    node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("title",function(d) { return d.name || d.layout; })
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

      node.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return 4.5; })
        .style("fill", color);

      node.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("fill","red") 
        .attr("stroke","red")           
        .style("font-size","9px")
        .on("click",click)
        .text(function(d){return d.name})
        .call(force.drag);


function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  //     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}
```

Here's the code that generates the faulty graph.

Comment: What do you mean by "the nodes are all displaced"?  The above should work if nothing else has been mixed up.

Comment: I mean that the nodes are no longer at the end of corresponding links but displaced to the right and bottom of where it should be. Yes it usually works and I have created a lot of force layouts where I have done it. The only difference in this case is that I am using d3.layout.links(nodes) to get the links.

Comment: I have attached 2 screenshots and the only change I have done is change from using cx,cy to using transform

Comment: Could you post your complete code please?

Comment: I posted the code that generates the graph.

Comment: You're setting the position coordinates twice -- don't set `cx`, `cy`, `x`, `y` for the `circle` and `text` elements inside the `g` if you're setting the translation.

Comment: Hey Lars, Yours is the right answer but I am unable to pick urs as the right 1

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the coordinates twice; on the actual elements and on the `g` containing them:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return 4.5; })
    .style("fill", color);
```

(similarly for the `text` elements) and

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});
```

This causes the offset. To fix, just set one of them (the translation on the `g` elements):

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return 4.5; })
    .style("fill", color);
node.append("text")
    .attr("fill","red") 
    .attr("stroke","red")
    // etc
```